# Is it safe to have power cables dangling outside the house?

Tags: electrical, walls, air-conditioning, subfloor

The bedroom split air conditioner gets it's power cable from the switches in the kitchen and goes under the tile floor to the bedroom. Problem is, it leads to an old switch fuse box thing that is far away from where the air conditioner. So previous occupants resorted to routing the cable from the outside in. So it starts from kitchen to bedroom then to outside then to bedroom again to connect to AC unit.

I asked electricians and they said to do it so it doesn't go outside, would be to tear up tiled floor. I asked for another way and he couldn't see an alternative because there is a beam through the wall that sits between the AC power source connection and the AC.

update with pic:

[image]

Comment: Dangling, no. Wires should be secured. Simply being outside, yes (assuming proper cable or conduit). I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: updated post to show pic of room. Its dangling as in it goes from one end to another without any support. Its meant to circumvent the rooms walls. Basically the power is on end of the room and the AC is on another. Cant be through walls, because of beam seen in pic that protrudes through the wall.

Comment: Looks like you might be several floors up. Is there access to the exterior so that cable could be put inside a conduit and properly secured to the wall?

Comment: behind that wall is the exterior, but since no windows there, there is no access i see.  But lets say there is one, there is a beam that divides the walls and the AC power source is on the wrong side of the divide, so i imagine to get to the other side, exterior or interior, it has to be dangling. but im not 100% sure.

Comment: Seems like maybe an interior surface-mount conduit (Wiremold) might be your best fix.

Comment: Wiremold is an option, but will bring the cables inside and visible. The electrician didnt have a problem having the cables out of site and outside. My guess is previous occupants were trying to avoid using wiremold so they took it outside instead. how about wiremold for the exterior?

Comment: What wiring method was used for the outside cable? Can we have photos of it?